# git repo size - practically how much size is good size for the git repo to work smoothly?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo size of **10 GB including(5 GB of codebase + 5 GB .git directory size)**. ".git" directory contains 12 years of history and 1.2 Million of objects(this size is after running git gc --aggressive).
Would it be slow for the team of 30 persons? Is the work impacted by the repo size?

Also, **We have not kept any binaries and files over 1 MB in the repo. It's just a codebase of multiple products**. We'll be having active developments going(team size 30) on in the repo in the future so is this size tolerable? Currently, we are migrating the repo from Perforce to git.

Need some expert view on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"codebase of multiple products"_ - do the products depend on each other, or share code between each other? If not, single repo per product might be a better approach. 5GB codebase is huge.

Comment: yes, they are too interconnected and dependent.

Comment: That suggests a deeper code smell with the codebase itself ... may be worth breaking into a more modular design so you can have independent repos.

Answer (score 1):

5GB for .git sounds 'large', but 12 years is 'long' time. There is no general answer but this as the computers and network speeds continue to evolve.

A more appropriate questions would be: Is it too slow for your team? Is work impacted by the repo size?

You may want to have a look at [10.7 Git Internals - Maintenance and Data Recovery](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery) and its `git gc --auto` (or with [`--agressive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt---aggressive).